# stuck on a simple preg_replace with backreference

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, regex-group, backreference

Sorry guys, I got stuck on this:

```
$data_update = preg_replace($id.'(.*?)'.$s.PHP_EOL, $id.$1.$s.$text.PHP_EOL, $data_update, 1);

$id = '23423';
$s = '|';
$text = 'content to insert';
```

Basically what I am trying to do is match everything that's between $id and a PHP End of Line in a flat file text that has multiple lines and replace it with the same line that has some content inserted right before the end of line. And I have the "1" modifier at the end because I want this to happen ONLY on the line that matches that id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use `$s="|"`? Please post the line example. Maybe you need `preg_replace('/\b(' . $id . '\b.*)(\R)/', '$1 ' . $text . '$2', $data_update, 1);`? See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/pRtIQ).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to patch for EOL because the end of line has been inserted in the flat file text as PHP_EOL so you can think of my data variable as this: 
   `$data_update = "23423 in between some text".PHP_EOL;`

   `$data_update .= "00000 in between some more text".PHP_EOL;`

   `$data_update .= "11111 in between even more text".PHP_EOL;`

Comment: If you need help, provide an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: your example helped and that PHP demo was great for me to figure it out! thank you! @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
preg_replace('/\b(' . $id . '\b.*)(\R)/', '$1 ' . $text . '$2', $data_update, 1);
```

The pattern will look like `\b(23423\b.*)(\R)` and will match

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(23423\b.*)` - Group 1: the ID as a whole word and then the rest of the line
- `(\R)` - Group 2: any line break sequence

See [full PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/pRtIQ):

```
$id = '23423';
$s = '|';
$text = 'content to insert';
$data_update = "Some text 23423 in between end\nsome text";
$data_update = preg_replace('/\b(' . $id . '\b.*)(\R)/', '$1 ' . $text . '$2', $data_update, 1);
```

Output:

```
Some text 23423 in between end content to insert
some text
```